# PHP Function to Add 'http://' to Strings

Tags: php, string, wordpress, function

I often use the following code on my WordPress builds in order to help prevent invalid links being added:

```
// add http:// if necessary
function addHttp($url) {
    if(substr($url, 0, 4) == 'www.') {
        $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

But this won't work should anyone add a link that *does* include a 'http://' but *doesn't* include a 'www.' in there too.

Does anyone know how I can modify my script to cater for this?

Comment: `oops.your.function.broke.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't assume that a URL will have `www` in it. Adding it will often break URLs.
2. Test to see if it starts with `http` or `https` and add the scheme if it doesn't

So:

```
function addHttp($url) {
  if(substr($url, 0, 4) != 'http') {
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
  }
  return $url;
}
```

Comment: It sounds you didn't read the question actually. And questioning the OPs motivation does not account as an answer, does it?

Comment: @hakre Why would you think that? This is a perfectly valid solution

Comment: @Doorknob:  I know you didn't read the question not even when it was quoted verbatim for a second time.

Comment: @hakre `in order to help prevent invalid links being added` That's exactly what this does.

Comment: To not really quote @Doorknob `http.oops.your.function.broke.com`.

Answer (score -5):

You need to check for that and then deal with the case as well, as you did already for the case you deal with.

I normally suggest the [`NetUrl2` class](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/) for URL handling as it makes such tasks extremely easy.

However, you can just do with the following modification, that not only normalizes the other parts you don't cover but also properly checks for the scheme. I've highlighted the part which adds the `www.` you asked for so you can easily remove it if you don't need that any longer:

```
function addHttp($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);

    $modif = function ($key, $prefix, $default = '') use (&$parts)
    {
        $parts[$key] = isset($parts[$key]) ? $prefix . $parts[$key] : $default;
    };

    $modif('scheme', '', 'http');
    $parts['scheme'] = strtolower($parts['scheme']);

    if (isset($parts['path']) && $parts['path'][0] !== '/')
    {
        $pathIsInPath  = strstr($parts['path'], '/', TRUE);
        $parts['host'] = $pathIsInPath ? : (isset($parts['host']) ? $parts['host'] : '') . $parts['path'];
        $parts['path'] = $pathIsInPath ? substr($parts['path'], strlen($pathIsInPath)) : '';
    }

    if (isset($parts['port']) && $parts['scheme'] === getservbyport($parts['port'], 'tcp')) {
        unset($parts['port']);
    }

    $modif('path', '', '/');
    $parts['path'] === '/' && $parts['path'] = '';

    // add www. if wanted
    if (substr($parts['host'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
        $modif('host', 'www.');
    }

    return sprintf('%s://%s%s%s%s%s', $parts['scheme'], $parts['host'], $modif('port', ':')
        , $parts['path'], $modif('query', '?'), $modif('fragment', '#'));
}
```